# Getting specific text on a page using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the following on a page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Reddit lazy load hack */
    var oScript = document.createElement("script");
    document.write = function(text) {
        document.getElementById("reddit").innerHTML += text;
    };
    oScript.src = "https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum.embed?limit=9";
    document.body.appendChild(oScript);

    setTimeout(function() {
    document.title = "Ethereum (ETH) $538.58 (2.21%) | ....";
    }, 10000);
});
```

The only part I am interested in is the **"ethereum"** part of the .src  of the script object
Is this possible with html agility pack or do i have to resort to `indexof/substring`

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to grab? Just the word "ethereum" or more than that?

Comment: @Justin multiple pages will have different words for where the word "ethereum" is located so I need to be able to extract out that part of the url, everything else is the same except the string "ethereum" will be the changing element, rest should be constant in that .src property